# NoMethodError: undefined method `updated_settings' for #<ActionMailer::Parameterized::Mailer:0x00005635bdaaa9d0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined, actionmailer

I am trying to send an email while using noticed gem version 1.4.1
This is my notification class

```
class Freelancer::UpdatePayoutSetting < Noticed::Base
  # Add your delivery methods
  deliver_by :database
  deliver_by :email, mailer: "FreelancerMailer", method: 'updated_settings'
  # deliver_by :slack
  # deliver_by :custom, class: "MyDeliveryMethod"

  # Add required params
  param :user

  # Define helper methods to make rendering easier.
  def message
    t("notifications.client.update_payout_setting.message", name: "#{params[:user]&.first_name} #{params[:user]&.last_name}")
  end

  def url
    freelancer_profile_path
  end
end
```

And this is my Mailer code

```
class FreelancerMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def updated_settings
    @user = params[:user]
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: "#{@user.name} Your Business Info Update successfully.")
  end
end
```

`

And this is my updated_settings.html.erb code for mailer action

```
<p>Hi <%= @user.name %>,</p>
<p>Your Payout Setting Update Successfully.</p>
<p>Regards,</p>
<p>Team Loovit</p>
```

I am calling this by running below command

Freelancer::UpdatePayoutSetting.with(user: current_user).deliver_later(current_user)

And its working fine on my local machine but it produces this Error on my production server

NoMethodError: undefined method `updated_settings' for #ActionMailer::Parameterized::Mailer:0x00005635bdaaa9d0

Comment: Are you certain the code deployed to your production server?

Comment: Yes other notification is working on my production but its not working